# Does getCurrentPosition() use GPS navigation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps

If I use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in any web page and visit it using web browser of any mobile device with GPS, will it use GPS navigation?
And how it will determine location if device has no GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Geolocation API is agnostic of the underlying location information sources](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#introduction) and therefore it is up to the browser (and device) to determine how the geolocation data is determined.

Comment: So, if I understood, answer is _yes_?

Comment: It *may* use GPS. It may also use Wifi triangulation or cell site geolocation. The point is the spec does not dictate how geolocation should be implemented, merely it defines a contract to say what geolocation should provide. If you as a manufacturer, can provide all of the items in the geolocation contract then you have implemented the API.

Answer (score 1):

See here for more details on how Firefox gets the geo location information from Google, http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI

Short answer is: they keep a database with the location of all wifi hotspots (most likely collected by the same cars that take streetview footage) and uses that information to provide location data.